# How to replace flag text with custom icon?

Tags: 7, views, media, flags

I am using [flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) and [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to show a "like" flag in a view. The machine name of my flag is "like". I want to replace the text of the flag with a heart icon. When it is not flagged, it is empty and when flagged, it is filled with red color as happens generally. I do not want to show icon besides text and neither I want to transform my flag into a button. If you have used instagram, you must know that there is a heart icon for a "like" flag. When someone clicks it, it becomes red. Like when you favorite a tweet on twitter.

I found this code, but do not know how to use it for my case. I am not sure whether it is the right code to use.

```
function Your_theme_preprocess_flag(&$vars) {
  $class = ($vars['action'] == 'flag') ? '<i class="fa fa-heart-o">   </i>' : '<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>';
  $vars['link_text'] = $class;
  $title_wishlist = ($vars['action'] == 'flag') ? 'Add to wishlist' : 'Remove from wishlist';
  $vars['link_title'] = $title_wishlist;
}
```

**Note:** I know I have to put it in template.php file of my theme. If you see the [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170867/how-to-add-a-custom-icon-or-symbol-to-a-flag-link/170876#170876), I took this code from there, but I have multiple flags on my site for example "like" "follow" "bookmark" etc etc. So I want to use this code for the "like" flag. How can i do that
I am also interested in learning how to add any icon other than heart and any flag I want.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170867/how-to-add-a-custom-icon-or-symbol-to-a-flag-link/170876#170876) ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I do not want to show icon besides text and neither I want to transform my flag into a button. If you have used instagram, you must know that there is a heart icon for a "like" flag. When someone clicks it, it becomes red. Like when you favorite a tweet on twitter

Comment: OK, this comment makes sense. Though I suggest you integrate that in your actual question. If appropriate with a link also to my "this"-link, to help explain the difference (for somebody who might think is smells like a duplicate).

Answer (score 1):

This code is needed in your *[template.php](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21themes%21seven%21template.php/7)* and a font-icon lybrary added like this one: http://fontawesome.io/icons/ There is a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome) for that to

Comment: I know I have to put it in template.php file of my theme. If you see the post above shared by pierre. I took this code from there, but I have multiple flags on my site for example "like" "follow" "bookmark" etc etc. So I want to use this code for the "like" flag. How can i do that?

Comment: @Umair : your prior comment may be worth integrating also in your question (as an additional refinement of your question).

Comment: @Umair you need to pass the "like" "follow" "bookmark" etc classes to views and generate `<i class="fa fa-like">` and others. Look around https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by "pass classes to views"?