# How to add an action button to item of content type page?

Tags: 7, views, theming, nodes, rules

I have a page which shows the details of an **Event** content type item. I added in my second sidebar a block which content a button. Here is a screenprint of what I have so far:

[image]

I want to use this button to update the status of the item (a field with machine name "`field_event_status`"). Before the validation I want to show a confirm popup.

Any help to get this to work?

Comment: Please review the edit I just applied to your question (trying to improve it). Feel free to further enhance it (eg: which Drupal version are you using? Or explain why you tagged this question with "rules"). If you don't like my edit at all, just perform a "rollback" to your prior question.

Comment: I see 2 buttons in your 2nd sidebar labeled "send invitation" and "Validate this event". Can you improve your question to indicate which "button" you want to use to perform that status update? Maybe also indicate if we can just ignore that other button in the context of this question here?

Comment: It's the bottom button I use. The button is inside a block.And I use Global textarea do design it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that you should start with using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, with a so called "global" flag. And configure your flag so that it would show an appropriate "confirmation" whenever such node gets flagged.

Next you could use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and create a custom rule like so:

- **Rules Event**: A node has been flagged, under "Some flag" (= the flag's label).
- **Rules Condition**: Entity has field (related to your `field_event_status` field), to make it available for further processing in subsequent Rules Events and/or Rules Actions.
- **Rules Action**: Set a data value (related to your `field_event_status` field).

With that you have the mechanics (logic) in place, and the only think left is theming the flag link(s) to have them shown as buttons. If you wonder how to make that happen also, then have a look at my answer to "[How to add a custom icon or symbol to a flag link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170867/how-to-add-a-custom-icon-or-symbol-to-a-flag-link/170876#170876)" (i.e. the **Option 2** part of it).

#### Tutorials

If you're not familiar with the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, checkout the [set of 8 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-flag) about the Flag module. Especially these tutorials from it:

- [Creating global flags and listing flagged content in Views](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/creating-global-flags-and-listing-flagged-content-in-views).
- [Triggering Rules with Flag](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/triggering-rules-with-flag)

#### More info

Refer to Flag's [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/flag) for (way) more details.

Comment: Thank for you good response. I take a look around it the video tutorials. I use DRUPAL 7

Comment: @Z.Lass : merci for the accept! Next question, if any? Or are you a flag/rules expert now?

Comment: hahahaha. Thank you!!! Not an expert. But it solved my problem. Are you use sometime  view php?yes, I have another question!

Comment: @Z.Lass : "views PHP"??? No, never (storing PHP in the database is bad ...). Similar answer about using Rules Conditions and Rules Actions that are "execute a PHP script".

Comment: Okey I open another question topic