# How to show picture of the user who triggered the rule for message activity?

Tags: 7, views, users, rules, message-subscribe

I am using [message module](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) to record user activity on the site and displaying it through [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). I am using [rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to trigger actions on certain events and show the relevant message.

How I can show picture of the user who triggered the event?

For example: When my question is liked by clive, I receive a message notification that "Clive liked your question". I only see a plain text. How to show the user picture?

Comment: *How* do you "receive a message"? Is that via some eMail (triggered by Rules or so), or is that an extra row that gets added in your view that displays the "Message" entities? Also, what do you have available in your Drupal site that contains such user picture?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Via email as well as on site after a rule is triggered. When you create a message type, you have 2 textareas, Subject and Body. I am talking about the body. I did not understand the last question.

Comment: Why did I receive a -20? There is a message as well, "user was removed". I asked another question regarding "How to convert flag link text to button". Do you know about that?

Comment: about my last question: what would be the url to be used if you want to browse such picture? or is it some image field of eg the user profile?

Comment: About your -20: you're not alone ... look at my profile (= -15). Has to do with some userid that got deleted (and which seemed to have voted a lot, so that are many upvotes of questions or answers that are now no longer upvoted by that user). About flag question: I saw that, but the closest I now of is like in my answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/170876/39516), which I think you did not want to use.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens If I understand correctly, It is user picture which is used by the system on the whole site. Picture directory which is defined at admin/config/people/accounts. Let me know if this is you wanted to know

Comment: Regarding flag Q, actually I read somewhere that text indent is not a good approach.

Comment: In the rule you're using, do you have any "token" available that corresponds to that picture of the user who triggered your event? If that's the case then I think I have an answer ...

Comment: I tried something. If you remember this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219680/which-user-related-tokens-can-be-used-to-create-a-rule-for-setting-up-a-messag?rq=1), I added @following_user_pic token in message type regarding **User Following**. Then I went to the rule and added a data set to actions and added this token and set a value [flagging-user:picture]. The approach is right I think, but the result is not right. Look at this.

Comment: This is how it is replacing the picture token. `<div class="user-picture"> <a href="/users/admin" title="View user profile."><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://almominoon.dd:8443/sites/almominoon.dd/files/styles/thumbnail/public/pictures/picture-1-1488082558.jpg?itok=7VIwNIcO" alt="admin&#039;s picture" title="admin&#039;s picture" /></a> </div>` admin started following

Comment: As you know user picture is not a field D7 which is shame. I found some guides to hack the core, but nothing worked for me. See this [post](https://www.drupal.org/node/967566). As a last resort, I guess I have to use [user picture field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_picture_field)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Mentioned you so that you receive notification of my comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to create your messages to be delivered, you can try to make the missing tokens available by using the ***Replacement patterns*** for each message type. Refer to the answer to [What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](http://drupal.placeto.be/node/109) for way more details on that (it explains how these Replacement tokens can be used to pass data available in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module).

With that, your only remaining challenge is to get access to the user picture in a custom rule. In D8 that picture has become a field also, but that's not the case in D7. Therefor you may get it to work in D7 also if you also use the [user picture field](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_picture_field) module (which doesn't have an official D7 release yet, but about 11K reported installs sounds like it's a pretty stable module).